# Reading nmap output with Ruby (basic issue)

Tags: ruby, network-programming, nmap

I want to build something that does a ping scan with nmap periodically to detect hosts showing up and dropping off the network. Is there an easy way to read the nmap output for Ruby? My preference is avoiding 3rd party libraries.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have several scripts that deal with `nmap` output, but I usually just use `-Ox` and then parse the XML result with Nokogiri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have learned that simply employing backticks around the command will allow me to capture the output as a variable:

test = `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24`
p 'test:'
puts test.split("\n")

Seems to work perfectly. However, as bonsaiviking pointed out, it would be wise to investigate nmap's XML functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to parse the text output of Nmap is the wrong way to go about it. The format has changed many times in the past, and will certainly change in the future. The proper way to do this is to parse Nmap's XML output, generated with the `-oX` argument. There are already a few Ruby libraries designed for this (Chris Gates covers this approach [on his blog](http://carnal0wnage.attackresearch.com/2010/01/ruby-nmap-xml-and-databases.html)), or you could start with an XML parser library and roll your own. [Nokogiri](http://nokokiri.org/) is a very good XML parsing library in Ruby.

Comment: Great point. I will work on implementing that later on. Right now, I'm just getting the tool functional and it's great to see it come together however trivial it might seem to anyone else. Would it be reasonable for a novice like myself to try parsing the XML file without a library or is that going to be too complicated?

Comment: "Getting the tool functional" will require a determination of what the function of the tool is. A large part of that is defining inputs and outputs. Unless you make it sufficiently modular, switching input formats will be difficult. It's also a mistake to think that using libraries is a negative. In trying to reinvent XML parsing, you are pretty much guaranteed to make common mistakes that a library would help you avoid.

Comment: It's hard to argue against that. I don't want to be in the habit of running away from libraries - they exist for a reason after all - but I do like to keep things as basic as possible so that I learn as much as possible since I yet still know so little. I guess, though, that learning to get along with libraries is certainly not something I would be wise to neglect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
require 'open3'
stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3('nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24')
```

Then you can parse stdout and stderr and get whatever you want using standard Ruby.

Comment: Did not have much luck with this. I kept getting "`spawn': can't convert true into String (TypeError)". Anyway, this problem is solved. Thank you for your help!